# Does codenameone web browser component now support blackberry?

Tags: codenameone

I want to write an application for BB using codenameone. I will like to use javascript code but I understand that the web browser component is not supported for BB. Is this still the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Codename One always supported the web browser component however the web browser component is flaky on RIM (for PhoneGap as well) so you could potentially get crashes and there won't be much we would be able to do about it.

It is just turned off by default, check out http://www.codenameone.com/advanced-build.html where `rim.nativeBrowser=true` is mentioned as the build argument.